# Shopware 6: Add custom Database Data to frontend view

Tags: php, symfony, twig, shopware, subscriber

Hello I have build my own custom shopware 6 Plugin. Now i want to add data from my own database table to the product page. My Subscriber works. But when I Want to add custom Database Data to Product Page. In my Subscriber for Products, I don't can use

```
$this->get('product_reservation.repository');
```

because "get" is not working into a subscriber.

How can I solve my Problem?

Comment: If I understand you properly you want to access container to get service with id `product_reservation.repository`. Generally it's not a good practice to acces container directly. Better to inject you dependencies via `constructor`.

Answer (score 1):

Inject it via class `__constructor` function.

Answer (score 0):

In subscriber,

```
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;

private $productRepository;

public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
{
   $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

In /plugins/Reservieren/src/Resources/config/services.xml file ,

add under services

```
<service id="ProduktReservieren\Subscriber\Reservieren">
    <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```